# What is meaning of <> in MS-SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I don't know what the is meaning of `<>` is in MS-SQL

**For example**:

```
IF(@userID <> '')
 Return 0;
ELSE
 Return -1;
```

Comment: It means not equal to. Stackoverflow is not a place to ask such basic questions. You could have searched it on google as well.

Comment: have you try to use google?

Answer (score 3):

[<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176020.aspx) means **not equal to** in Transact-SQL.

> Compares two expressions (a comparison operator). When you compare nonnull expressions, the result is TRUE if the left operand is not equal to the right operand; otherwise, the result is FALSE.

Answer (score 3):

In Transact SQL, `<>` means `NOT EQUAL TO`

Check [msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

As it would logically imply:

> x <> y

if x is greater then or less then y.

Even simpler, **not equal**.

Answer (score 3):

As you ask for MYSQL, Its one of the comparison operator.

[MYSQL Documentation for Comparison Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

<> Means "Not equal operator"

Answer (score 2):

`<>` in MS SQL means **"NOT EQUAL TO".**

In your case `IF(@userID <> '')` means IF variable `@userID` IS NOT EQUAL to `''` THEN

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173258.aspx) it is *not equal*

Answer (score 0):

<> is a comparison operator meaning "not equal to" 
This is used to compare two expressions and will result to a boolean value.
Thank you! :)